# error when calling exslt in Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon, exslt

I get the error message:

> "Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named
>   {http://exslt.org/common}node-set()"

when running a xslt transformation with the Saxon engine.

I've tried using Saxon PE and EE on Windows XP and it gives the same error. EXSLT should work out of the box with Saxon. Does anyone have a solution on how I may resolve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon PE and EE are XSLT 2.0 processor implementations where you don't need a node-set extension function as in XSLT 2.0 the difference between result tree fragments and node-sets does no longer exists. So you should be able to simply use e.g. `$var/foo/bar` instead of `exsl:node-set($var)/foo/bar` in your stylesheets where you process variables.